# Amazon Quicksight - is it possible to invoke APIs in Quicksight?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-quicksight

I am new to AWS. I have to design an architecture for a client specifically with AWS, as they already use some AWS components. Their request is to have a frontend in Quicksight. The alerts should be visible in a table, each row representing one alert. The alerts should have a status column (new/in progress/solved etc.) and there should be a button at the end of every row, and when the user clicks on the button, the user should receive a pop-up, where they can put in some comments, then after clicking on an OK button, the status should be updated and the comments should be stored.

Their expectation is to store the alerts history in an AWS database. They currently use ProstgreSQL on premise. The question is, is Quicksight able to fulfill these requirements? Is it possible to add buttons with which the user can make updates in an underlying database, and refresh Quicksight, when the update was done? If not, what would be a better tool for the visualization?
(I was planning to create some APIs for making updates in a database, my original plan was to use DynamoDB, but I might need to reconsider this due to their preference regarding ProsgreSQL).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is directly possible in QuickSight. There is no way to provision external controls (like buttons) and trigger actions right away. However, a possible workaround can be using a blended way to use QuickSight APIs and trigger events from a web app using AWS Lambda. This is not a proven practice yet, but I anticipate this is possible.
Cheers!